# Oracle: I can find query in sharedpool, but i can not find query in source code. Where does it come from?

Tags: sql, oracle

With sql below I can find a specific query in the Oracle sharedpool, that is taking 10s and is executed approximately once every 10 minutes. But I can not find this query in source code.

```
SELECT sql_id, hash_value, plan_hash_value, child_number, executions,
round(buffer_gets/executions) AS buffer_per_exec,
round(physical_read_bytes/executions/8192) AS phys_per_exec,
round(elapsed_time/executions/1000) as elapsed_time, 
TO_CHAR (last_active_time, 'DD/Mon/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as last_active_time, 
IS_OBSOLETE, IS_BIND_SENSITIVE, IS_BIND_AWARE, IS_SHAREABLE
FROM v$sql
WHERE sql_text NOT LIKE '%v$sql%'
AND  round(buffer_gets/executions) > 40000
AND executions > 0
ORDER BY to_date(last_active_time) DESC, elapsed_time, phys_per_exec DESC;
```

When I execute

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(<sql_id>, <child_id>, 'allstats peeked_binds last'));
```

I get the output:

```
SELECT "A1"."T1_ID","A1"."T4_ID","A2"."T1_ID","A2"."T3_ID" 
FROM "TABLE1" "A1","TABLE2" "A2" WHERE "A2"."T1_ID"="A1"."T1_ID"
```

What I wonder is whenever I explain_cursor for any other query, I don't get the result in ""(double quotes).

If I lookup in v$sesion with:

```
select v.* from v$session v
where <sql_id> in (v.prev_sql_id, v.sql_id);
```

I get the SID, SERIAL# and so on, but I see it as a ORACLE.EXE program.

Who is calling this query? Where can I find it? Is it possible that query is executed through a database link? Why is query in sharedpool in double qoutes?

Comment: Note: A1 and A2 are automatically generated. We never use A1 and A2 as table naming in queries.

Comment: check the machine, program and module columns from v$session

Comment: Machine = Machine name that oracle is running on.
Module= oracle.exe
Program= oracle.exe

Comment: If your tables are application tables then it's probably a job, did you look for jobs  (dba_jobs or dba_scheduler_jobs)

Comment: Tables are my application tables. No job is querying those tables. Interesting is that the style of writing query with naming querying tables with A1 and A2 is not something that we have in our source code. Is maybe oracle transforming query because it maybe came in from database link? I have never seen anything like this. Or maybe this is just the way that query is presented in sharedpool.

Comment: Thank you Cyrille MODIANO, if I looked more carefully, I would see that machine is not the server this oracle is running on, but it is the remote one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical of remote queries executed via a database link, e.g

```
select * from myschema.mytable@otherdb
```

will be rewritten and executed on the remote side by the database gateway as:

```
select "A1"."COL1",
       "A1"."COL2"
  from "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" "A1"
```

You can confirm this by inspecting the `machine` column of the `V$SESSION` view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got little confused when looking through both systems and I messed up machine column in the v$session. So my prediction was right. Queries are rewritten when executed via database link. Thank you. Now I know in which source code I have to look for this query.